# Stun/Turn usage in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, sip, stun, turn, ice-protocol

I am developing a small webrtc application in C. I am making a webrtc call using sip signalling. I have below queries regarding usage of stun/turn/ice.

When I start call I send INVITE with offer (SDP).  In SDP we need to put ICE candidates.

I have two possible cases. To explain it I will take an example. Say two endpoints are **A** and **B**. I have  a sip proxy server say **P**. Also I have a turn server (supports both stun and turn), say it is **T**.

**Case 1**
All entities **A**, **B**, **P** and **T** are in same private network. Is STUN resolution required here? If yes then what all stun requests/responses I need to deal with?

**Case 2** 
Here **A** is in private network. Other entities **B**, **P** and **T** are in public network. In this case I hope we need to do STUN/TURN resolution. Lets say I started with STUN, and got host and reflexive candidates. I see in some examples, *Permission* , *Channel Bind* requests are also used. If I am using just STUN (no TURN), after I get host and reflective candidates then do I need to do anything extra?

Besides this, is there any good open source available for stun/turn client in C that uses gnutls (no openssl)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 - No.  Not required, per se. It's just that there's no easy way to detect when an INVITE comes from the same network as you are on.

Case 2 - If you are just using STUN, local host and reflexive candidates are fine. TURN is used for scenarios when relays are required (symmetric NAT scenarios).

Comment: So in case 2, initially I will be sending STUN bind request, from response I will get host candidates and reflexive candidates. I will go ahead and use IP/port present in reflexive candidate for building SDP and proceed with call. Now do I need to send any more STUN request during lifetime of this call. Please clarify.

Comment: No you don't. STUN is used only for gathering your server reflexive candidate. You don't need it anymore after that.

Comment: Just to verify, I installed sipml5 (sip-webrtc client in javascript) in two machines in a private network. Sip server I used from public network (sip2sip.info). I made a call between two sipml5 endpoints. I observed, initially sipml5 is sending stun request to stun server, after call establishment, I see stun bind packets are exchanged between two sipml5 endpoints. Why it is so, here both sipml5 endpoints are in my network, ideally they should not exchange stun bind requests. Is it because I am making use of public stun server and public sip server ?

Comment: Sipml5 employs ICE protocol for establishing connection between two endpoints. According to ICE protocol connectivity checks between two end points, named ICE check requests, are done through STUN Binding packets. Thats what you are seeing.